# Google Cloud Datastore request returns Error 400 in my browser

Tags: c#, c++, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-datastore

After many trials and errors I managed to compile a piece of code which should return Entities' values from Google Datastore (it's SQL-like db). Code I used:

```
static async void Run()
{
    UserCredential credential;
    using (var stream = new FileStream(@"c:/fakepath/client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            new[] { DatastoreService.Scope.Datastore }, "user", CancellationToken.None);
    }

    // Create the service.
    var service = new DatastoreService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        ApplicationName = "My Project",
        HttpClientInitializer = credential
    });

    // Run the request.
    Console.WriteLine("Executing a list request...");

    var request = new LookupRequest();
    var key = new Google.Apis.Datastore.v1beta2.Data.Key();
    key.Path = new List<KeyPathElement> { new KeyPathElement() { Kind = "book", Name = "title42" } };
    request.Keys = new List<Key>() { key };

    var lookup = service.Datasets.Lookup(request, "project-name-192"); //yea
    var response = lookup.Execute();

    // Display the results.
    if (response.Found != null)
    {
        foreach (var x in response.Found)
        {
            foreach (var y in x.Entity.Properties)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(y.Key.FirstOrDefault() + " " + y.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error I get:
[image: What am I missing?]
So, what am I missing? I did just like in example on docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to:

https://console.developers.google.com/project/apps~{your-app-name}/apiui/credential

and use `http://localhost:63324/authorize/` as the redirect url.

Remember to change it to your production url when you deploy

Comment: Oh thanks! And what url do I need to use if I am testing on google cloud? I mean, now it's redirecting me to localhost. Why not my project url on google cloud?

Comment: Well, once you deploy, it should be something like: `http://www.yoursite.com/authorize/` or `https://yourapp.appspot.com/authorize/`

Comment: It doesn't let me change the `REDIRECT URIS` on credential page. It stays localhost, which I don't use.

Comment: Do I have to have a local web server to receive responses? I thought it will respond to my program directly.

Comment: Is not your app running at `http://localhost:63324`?  If not, then use the local address your app is running in development.

Comment: Yea I was reading more and more docs and if I understand correctly, it opens a browser for an user and he must accept and grant access, then he gets the token to call API. Is there Any way to receive that key without prompting the request through the browser?

Comment: No.  That is oauth.  It is a handshake between the user and the service (Google in this case).  You cannot control it, for obvious reasons.  You could use another auth system, like just having the user sign into their Google account, or your own user auth system, or require no authorization at all.  But, that is a separate question.